Troubleshooting a circular saw that has lost power
I have a 10-year-old Black and Decker corded circular saw. I am a hobbyist so I don't use it very often. The other that I had to split a very long, quite thick log and I used it. Half way through, I see (and hear) that it's losing power, but I continued.
I probably burned something inside, but the circular saw keeps working, but as if the engine was half as powerful. I can still turn it on, be definitely with less kick as before .
With this limited information, can anyone theorize whether it is salvageable? Do circular saws have fuses inside and I would only need to replace one?

what type of motor is inside it? if it's a brushed motor you might need to clean the commutator and/or clean/replace the brushes.

Do a bunch of work to take it apart and look for hours to find parts, ( That you may or may not find) and then find you are missing at least 1 screw when trying to put it back together.  If you have time to spare, go for it.    Or buy a new one.

On the sides of the motor case you should see a pair of small caps oriented opposite each other. Open them with a coin or large screwdriver and inspect. If the metallic block on the end of the spring is very short, they're due for replacement.
If they're not, blow any dust out of the motor area, clean the brushes with alcohol, and reinstall. That should regain lost contact.
If you still don't have full power, the windings or other internal motor components may be damaged. A garage sale replacement is in order.
